# Automatically downloading Groovy console logs from Soap UI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have Soap UI Pro. I am able to download all the system generated reports. I have a groovy script as one of the test steps and I am writing some transaction logs using log.info(). When I execute my test suite, I also want my console logs to be automatically downloaded to my machine. Can someone let me know if this is possible ?

or can I write my log.info() values to the system generated logs ?

Comment: `log.info()` is written to `global-groovy.log`.

Comment: Sounds great. I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

There is my script to save the Script log to a file.

```
def loggerSize = 0

log.info "first log"
log.info "second log"

def logArea = null
logArea = com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.logMonitor.getLogArea( "Script log" ); // Or HHTP log, Jetty log, Script log;  each tab name in log part, can't capture 'Log Output' part ... 
def model = null
def logger = ""
if( logArea != null ){
    model = logArea.model
    if( model.size > loggerSize ){
        for(c in loggerSize..(model.size-1)){
            logger += model.getElementAt(c).toString() + "##"
        }
    }
}
return logger
```

Comment: I will try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Hi Lerminou, This script is returning model.size as 0 and hence couldnt get into for loop. I have some log.info() lines before where I am actually calling this function. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Thx Lerminou, Tried this one. No luck yet though. Attached my code and log. Not sure. logArea is returned but size still is zero.

Comment: LOG:  Fri May 08 10:39:05 AEST 2015:INFO:first log
Fri May 08 10:39:05 AEST 2015:INFO:second log
Fri May 08 10:39:05 AEST 2015:INFO:logArea is  : com.eviware.soapui.support.log.JLogList[,2,25,-5x-28,hidden,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder@6b58f6,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
Fri May 08 10:39:05 AEST 2015:INFO:INSIDE ELSE : model.zie : 0loggerSize is : 0
Fri May 08 10:39:05 AEST 2015:INFO:logger output is

Comment: Which soapui version are you using ? My version is for ready API! If you use only soapui you maybe need to use "script log" instead of" Script log" he is case sensitive. Look my comment in the script.. The name need to be the same as the tab you want to captur. But he can't capture the 'log output'part when you only run the teststep

Comment: I have API Ready as well and used Script Log still no luck. As an alternative, I created a file and writing all logs onto that file instead of info.log().. Addressing my need as of now though.